# A class's instance gets destroyed when inner class's method exits?

Tags: java

I am going to use `Xposed Bridge` API to customize my status bar on my Android phone.
Hooking methods are working pretty well, but there's a problem.

```
public class WPSModule implements IXposedHookLoadPackage {
    final int ICON_SIZE = 100;

    FrameLayout FlStatusBar;
    ...

    void HideWidget(FrameLayout FlLayout, String Name)
    {
        int ViewId = FlLayout.getResources().getIdentifier(Name, "id", "com.android.systemui");
        if(ViewId == 0)
        {
            XposedBridge.log("Failed to find resource " + Name + " on systemui package.");
            return;
        }
        View v = FlLayout.findViewById(ViewId);
        if(v == null)
        {
            XposedBridge.log("v == null with resource " + Name + " on systemui package.");
            return;
        }
        v.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }

    public static TextView TvText = null;

    public void handleLoadPackage(final LoadPackageParam LppParam) throws Throwable {
        if (!LppParam.packageName.equals("com.android.systemui"))
            return;
        XposedBridge.log("WPS: SystemUI package found.");

        //Hook
        findAndHookMethod("com.android.systemui.statusbar.phone.PhoneStatusBarView", LppParam.classLoader, "onFinishInflate", new XC_MethodHook() {
            @Override
            protected void beforeHookedMethod(MethodHookParam MhpParam) throws Throwable {
                // this will be called before the clock was updated by the original method
            }

            @Override
            protected void afterHookedMethod(MethodHookParam MhpParam) throws Throwable {
                FlStatusBar = (FrameLayout) MhpParam.thisObject;
            }
        });
        ....
    }
}
```

And when I try to use FlStatusBar like this:

```
HideWidget(FlStatusBar, "notification_lights_out");
```

It doesn't work. On Xposed's log...

```
07-31 20:22:09.962 E/Xposed (18737): java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources android.widget.FrameLayout.getResources()' on a null object reference.
```

Other things which uses `FlStatusBar` doesn't work too..(ex: `FlStatusBar.toString()` gives me `NullPointerException`)

Comment: Where do you actually assign a value to FlStatusBar?

Comment: `static TextView` < that's a leak. Please don't.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen I am assigning status bar layout object to FlStatusBar. I used new keyword to create a TextView before, but it didn't worked. That object gone, too.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen I tried this: I declared a variable i on class(assign 0 as default value) and in afterHookedMethod, assign 1 to i. And when I print variable i outside of afterHookedMethod, it shows me 0. This thing never happens when I write simple program using eclipse.